# Какова грамматика у сочетания "уж на что"?

Tags: грамматика, фразеология

**Уж на что, на что,** а на такое прибыльное дельце смекалки у него хватит. [В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга третья. Ч. 2 (1934-1945)]

Здесь все понятно, **падежная  форма** местоимения (***на что — на дельце***).

Но чаще это выражение выступает **в роли наречия степени,** и вот тогда его структура не очень понятна, например:

**Уж на что** терпеливым и с пониманием был Александр Иванович, но тут сорвался: [Геннадий Пруцков, 2003]

**И уж на что** равнодушна была к своей родине государыня Анна Иоанновна, но и в ней шевельнулось чувство удивленной гордости за обильную и могучую страну, коей призвана она управлять. [Ю. М. Нагибин(1972-1979)]

Answer (score 3):

Это словосочетание, вообще-то, фразеологическое, обозначает "без всякого сомнения, совершенно определённо".

Ефремова говорит, что это союз, который "употребляется при присоединении придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, в которой наряду с полнотой, исчерпанностью признака содержится уступительное ограничение". Синонимы: хотя и, несмотря на то что, на что.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/258044/%D0%A3%D0%B6

*Уж на что терпеливым и с пониманием был Александр Иванович, но тут сорвался*.

**=**

*Хотя и  терпеливым и с пониманием был Александр Иванович, но тут сорвался*.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уступительное значение здесь, безусловно,  присутствует. Но ведь можно сказать: уж какой он был терпеливый ... Значит, у союза есть варианты. Но меня еще интересовало происхождение этой формы: как "на что" приобрело такое значение?

Comment: @Jasmin У вас в вопросе две _разных_ формы рассмотрены (и два соответствующих им примера). В ответе Людмилы рассмотрена только вторая (**уж на что**). Грамматику можно предположить такую (она не противоречит подстановке "хотя"): (даже **уж**е несмотря) **на** (то, ) **что**. Первая форма - другая: **Что-что, А** (у вас - её предложно-падежная модификация: _на что, на что, ... а_). Она отдельно толкуется у Ефремовой: _част. разг. Употребляется при выделении субъекта или объекта речи, соответствуя по значению сл.: уж что-что, а._ https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/266706/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: Хорошо, но я первую конструкцию просто для сравнения привела, меня же интересует вторая. Откуда там направленный В.п. (на что), как вы думаете? Предположите что-нибудь, желательно в форме ответа.

Comment: Направленный В.п там из древности. Древнерусский предлог на выражал много значений: на, через, сверх, против, вместо, к, для, про, об, при и   др. Соединение "на" с указательным местоимением i в усилительном значении дало приставку "наи"(наилучший), обознач. высшую степень чего-то; "что"  по происхождению тоже указат. мест. ч+то ; на + что  дало наречие начто = насколько - тоже высшая степень чего-то. Потом слово видоизменилось во фразеологизм "уж на что", а значение осталось. Видимо, по аналогии с "уж как сильно", "насколько сильно"= на что, на сколько, на какую степень сильно.

Answer (score 1):

По Далю, во фразеологическом обороте **уж на что** составляющая "*начто*" (тогда писалось слитно) "*выражает **высшую степень** чего-либо*". Ему синонимично более ясное, буквальное выражение "**уж насколько**". Высшей степени чего-либо, приведённого в начале высказывания, *противопоставляется* парадоксальный факт, по схеме: "*При том, насколько сильно выражено такое-то качество, имело место неожиданное*". Применительно к примерам из вопроса:

> **И уж на что** равнодушна была к своей родине государыня Анна Иоанновна, но и в ней шевельнулось чувство...
>
> **Известно, насколько** равнодушна была к своей родине государыня Анна Иоанновна, но и в ней шевельнулось чувство...

Без "но":

> **При том, сколь** равнодушна была к своей родине государыня Анна Иоанновна, *даже* в ней шевельнулось чувство...
>
> **Сколь ни был** терпелив и с пониманием Александр Иванович, тут он
>   сорвался.

Comment: Спасибо, я учла ваше мнение в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я просматривала примеры с "на что",  мне встретилось выражение **"на что уж лучше", по аналогии с "куда уж лучше".**

Я подумала, что в сочетаниях с прилагательными тоже может присутствовать **сравнительная степень:** на что (куда уж) равнодушнее, терпеливее.

Отсюда смысл такой: **настолько терпеливый (равнодушный), что куда уж терпеливее (равнодушнее).**

Может быть, так можно объяснить.